# How to check if a value exists in one of several lists

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
answer = int(input("input number in range 1-6: "))
yes = [1, 2, 3]
no = [4, 5, 6]
while answer not in yes:
    print("what?")
    answer = int(input())
else:
    if answer in no:
        print("no")
    elif answer in yes:
        print("yes")
```

I want the `while` loop to terminate if the number is in either the `yes` list or the `no` list. How can I include the second list in the `while` loop condition correctly?

Comment: `while answer not in yes and answer not in no:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the lists using the addition operator:

```py
while answer not in yes + no:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `and`:

```
while answer not in yes and answer not in no:
```

Also, there are other ways you can concatenate `yes` and `no`:

- `while answer not in [*yes, *no]:`
- You could add `import itertools` and check both the lists with `while answer not in itertools.chain(yes, no):`
- `while answer not in [j for i in zip(yes, no) for j in i]:`